# Time transformation of scalar field

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, calculus

Suppose $\delta\phi$ is scalar field perturbation; and the scalar field is a function of time $\phi(t)$. Under the transformation  $t\rightarrow t +\delta t$, the perturbation transformation become

$$\delta \phi \rightarrow \delta\phi - \dot{\phi}\delta t  $$

Can anyone prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $t \mapsto t + \delta t$ means that your field is basically now a function $\phi(t- \delta t)$. Taylor expanding the field perturbation gives your quoted result.